# How to find common values from two array using pthread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define MAX_THREAD 4

long long int arr1[100];
long long int arr2[100];

int n,m;
int part = 0;

void* array_search(void* arg){

    int thread_part = part++;

    //printf("%d\n",thread_part);

    if(part==4)
    {
        for(int i = thread_part *(n/4) ; i < n ; i++){
            for(int j = thread_part*(m/4) ; j < m;j++){
                if(arr1[i] == arr2[j]){
                    printf("%lld\n", arr1[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        for(int i = thread_part *(n/4) ; i < ((thread_part + 1) *(n/4)) ; i++){
            for(int j = thread_part*(m/4) ; j < ((thread_part + 1) *(m/4));j++){
                if(arr1[i] == arr2[j]){
                    printf("%lld\n", arr1[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}

int main()
{
    printf("Enter the element in First Array:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%lld",&arr1[i]);
    }   
    printf("Enter the element in Second Array:");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < m; i++){
        scanf("%lld",&arr2[i]);
    }
    pthread_t thread[MAX_THREAD];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++){
        pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, array_search, (void*)NULL); 
    } 
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++){
        pthread_join(thread[i], NULL); 
    }
            
    return 0;
}
```

Actually there is a problem in my code. When I enter the following input it's printing nothing. I don't understand why this is happening.

```
Enter the element in First Array:3
2000 4000 5000 
Enter the element in Second Array:4
2000 70000 40000 300000
(no output here)
```

Comment: You have data race on `part`. Not sure what `if(part==4) ... else ..` is supposed to achieve. More importantly, do you have to use threads to solve this? :-)

Comment: Yes, part==4 says all threads are running, but part is modified by threads, is not protected by a mutex, and so can be corrupted.  Your for ranges are not ending on thread_part derived values.  If you check the first 1/4 of a against the first 1/4 of b, you are checking 1/16 of the possibilities.

Comment: i add part == 4 beacuse for last thread i have to consider the all elements in the array

Comment: but i din't understant what are you trying to say can you explain this more deply